# Django-Twilio sending SMS on button click

Tags: python, django, twilio

OK possible noob question here: While learning Django, I thought it might be cool to explore telephony with Twilio. My immediate goal is to create a page with a button that, when clicked, causes a "Hello World" SMS to be sent to my phone. After sorting that out I have some ideas for cooler stuff.

I've completed several Django tutorials so far, and made a few little apps with simple views. But nothing I've learned has particularly shed any light on how to do something like this. I've also investigated (and installed) the Django-Twilio app and the Twilio Python Helper Library, but the docs for neither of these show how to send "hello world" SMS's.

Can anyone point out a resource that might show how to do this? Or, if it's trivially easy, just post some example code?

Edit in response to Kevin Burke:

Thanks for getting back to me, Kevin.
After modifying my urls.py to include:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ...
url(r'^sms/$', 'django_twilio.views.sms', {
    'message': 'Hello world',
    'to': '+12223334444',
    'sender': '+18882223333',
    'status_callback': '/sms/completed/',
    }, name = 'send_message'),
# ...
)
```

and pointing my browser at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sms/
```

the following error arises:

```
Exception Type: TwimlException at /sms/
Exception Value: Invalid method parameter, must be 'GET' or 'POST'
```

Perhaps this is because I have failed to make appropriate modifications to the view. But I don't have a good way of figuring out what I'm doing wrong from the minimal examples in the tutorial.
/Edit

Comment: It's a little tricky to help out without knowing more about your situation. It's definitely possible to send "Hello World" using the twilio-python helper library, see for example https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install, but without knowing where you are getting stuck it's tricky to offer more feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

twilio employee here. 
The problem here is that the built in views for `django_twilio` run through a series of validation checks to make sure they're receiving content from twilio.com and only twilio.com. This is a security measure built into `django-twilio`.

There are two things you can do:

1. Make sure your `settings.DEBUG = True` in your Django settings, this will turn off the validation. You can then send a `cURL` request on your local machine whilst it is running like this in your terminal:

   ```
   $ curl http://localhost:8000/sms/
   ```

   This should return some [TWiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) like so:

   ```
   <Response><Sms>Hello world</Sms></Response>
   ```
2. When you're running this online and you want to do to test this, set up your [twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming) to point to `http://mywebsite.com/sms/` and text the number. Ensure that `settings.DEBUG = False` and you should get back a message.

If you have anymore problems, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official docs: [django-twilio official docs](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/0.2/). More specifically, read this part about sending SMS: [Sending sms messages](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/0.2/views.html#sending-sms-messages)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple solution :**

```
django startproject projectname
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('message_api.urls')),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION = False
DJANGO_TWILIO_BLACKLIST_CHECK = True
```

> **Start new application**

```
python manage.py startapp appname
```

> Inside the app folder:`

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import django_twilio
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^api/$', views.home),
     url(r'^send/', views.sms),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio_api import settings

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def sms(request):
    client = Client(settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)

    message = client.messages.create(to='TO NUMBER', from_='YOUR TWILIO NUMBER', body='This message is sent through twilio api using django framework by akshat.')

    print(message.sid)

    return render(request, 'thankyou.html')
```

> Make a templates directory inside your app folder

**index.html**

```
<body>
<a href="/send/"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Send Message</button></a>
</body>
```

**thankyou.html**

```
<body>
<h1>Success</h1>
</body>
```

`

Comment: where the message sends action done. Is it in  print(message.sid) ??